# Need my current .htaccess upgraded

Tags: .htaccess

So, this is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The idea was to have www forced upon each user, no matter if the user visits my domain with or without www and at the same time, that user needs to be redirected to "folder" or in other words to www.mydomain.com/folder .

Although this code works perfectly, I want it also to redirect users to www.mydomain.com/folder when they go anywhere on mydomain.com domain except /folder. For example: (www.)mydomain.com/index.html (or any other page) and (www.)mydomain.com/anyotherfolder needs to be redirected to www.mydomain.com/folder

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this additional rule after your existing rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^folder http://www.mydomain.com/folder/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Your code works, however, I just figured the flaw in my own part. When I am at www.mydomain.com/folder and I delete www and hit refresh, I end up getting mydomain.com/folder without www. How can i fix that?